# ¿Cómo muestro las líneas que tengan palabras que inicien con una letra y que terminen con otra letra? | LINUX

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, grep, procesamiento-de-texto

Debo hacer lo siguiente: **Mostrar las líneas que tengan palabras que inicien con M y terminen con Z.**

Sé como buscar y mostrar líneas que tengan palabras que comiencen con una respectiva letra: `grep '\<M'`

Pero no sé cómo hacer que me busque una palabra que comience con una letra en específico y que la misma palabra termine con otra letra.

Se me ocurrió que podría ser `grep '\<M.*\>Z'` pero no me da nada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes usar `^` para indicar el principio de línea y `$` para indicar el final:

```
grep '^M.*Z$' fichero
```

---

Por ejemplo dado el fichero:

```
$ cat fichero
MZ
Me gusta la Z
Me gusta la N
bla bla bla
la Z
Mmmmm
```

Sale esto:

```
$ grep '^M.*Z$' fichero
MZ
Me gusta la Z
```

Comment: Disculpa pero en vez de que sean líneas que empiecen con M y terminen con Z, será que me muestres las líneas que contengan palabras que empiecen con M y terminen con Z, por ejemplo;

Esta línea contiene la palabra Maíz

Donde Maíz comienza con M y termina con Z

Comment: Esto debería ser pues `grep -iE '\bm[^ ]*z\b'`. De todos modos, creo mejor plantear una pregunta nueva para este caso.